# SQLAlchemy and INET Array in Python ( no Flask )

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How can you load a table with INET ARRAY type?

```
cidr_table = db.Table('cidr_table', metadata,
        db.Column('range_name', db.String(255), nullable=False),
        db.Column('wide_range_cidr', postgresql.INET(), nullable=False),
        db.Column('used_cidr_list', postgresql.ARRAY(??????))
        )
```

I am trying to get the used_cidr_list to be an array of INET values which will be populated like [10.0.0.0/10, 10.1.0.0/16, and so on ]

How can i achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25730892/5320906).

Answer (score 2):

## There is the same method of using INET with or without flask

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INET

class Hosts(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'hosts'

    host_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.Identity(), primary_key=True)

    host_name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    host_ip_addresses = db.Column(db.ARRAY(INET()), nullable=True)
```

So in your case,
It will be

```
    db.Column('used_cidr_list', db.ARRAY(INET()))
```